# Julia: How to do a by with columns defined as CategoricalArrays.NullableCategoricalArray{String,1,Int32}?

Tags: julia, feather

I have been struggling with a dataframe loaded in from Feather.jl when I try to do a by

```
using Feather,DataFrames, DataFramesMeta, CategoricalArrays

a = Feather.read("some_file.feather")
# the below fails
aaa = by(a, :some_col, df -> sum(df[:some_val]))
```

it gives an error

*MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type CategoricalArrays.CategoricalValue{String,Int32}*

The type information is as per below

```
typeof(a)
# DataFrames.DataFrame

typeof(a[:some_col]) 
# CategoricalArrays.NullableCategoricalArray{String,1,Int32}

typeof(a[:some_val])
# NullableArrays.NullableArray{Float64,1}
```

The [documentation for CategoricalArrays](http://juliadata.github.io/CategoricalArrays.jl/stable/using.html) doesn't contain a lot of documentation on working with DataFrames (nor should it I guess)

However I tried to replace the column with a test value then the by works.

```
a[:some_col] = ["Testing" for i in 1:nrow(a)]
#this works
by(a,:some_col, df -> sum(df[:some_val]))
```

so it must be something wrong with CategoricalArrays. But I can't figure out how to do this simple summary. Please help

Comment: To convert from NullableCategoricalArray to DataArray use: `df_from_a = DataFrame(some_col = get.(get.(a[:some_col],Nullable{NAtype}(NA))), some_val = get.(get.(a[:some_val],Nullable{NAtype}(NA))))`. There should be an easier method but this should work. Now use `by(df_from_a, :some_col, df -> sum(df[:some_val]))`

Comment: Please edit your question, so "edited" code actually parses. See for example missing `)` on `by(a,:some_col, df -> sum(df[:some_val])` in the question.

Comment: Thanks @DanGetz I've fixed the above and you are right I had to make many changes to protect sensitivity of data.

Comment: @DanGetz The get.(get.(...)) method works but I guess it's not ideal. Ideally the categoricalarrays should just work right of the box https://github.com/JuliaData/CategoricalArrays.jl/issues/80